# How does OpenGl actually paint a triangle?

Tags: algorithm, opengl, graphics, opengl-es, directx

Suppose there is a triangle in the NDCS space.
Maybe OpenGL will do viewport transformation and draw the triangle.

In many graphics books, they introduce a lot of ways to draw a filled polygon.
However, I really want to know how OpenGl works.

I believe  in a simple situation(There are no transparent or translucent objects there), the Z-Buffer algorithm would be enough, do you think Scan-line fill algorithm and other algorithms need?

I think we can determine the color of a pixel through the z-buffer algorithm.

Please let me know the details of the process.

Comment: OpenGL doesn't require any specific algorithm, it just describes some formal requirements on the rasterization, and implementations are free to use any algorithm they see fit. I think your question is way to broad for stack overflow. However, Fabian Giesen's blog series [A trip through the Graphics Pipeline 2011](https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/07/09/a-trip-through-the-graphics-pipeline-2011-index/) might be a good read, as it describes what _GPUs_ actually do. [Part 6](https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/a-trip-through-the-graphics-pipeline-2011-part-6/) is about rasterization.

Comment: Answering in "detail" is many books worth of material. You're not going to get a good answer on SO. The spec alone for OpenGL ES is 400 pages, and that just describes "what", not "how". This book is a good one: http://www.realtimerendering.com/

Answer (score 0):

From the OpenGL specifications:

> ...rasterizing a primitive consists of two parts. The first is to
>   determine which squares of an integer grid in window coordinates are
>   occupied by the primitive. The second is assigning a depth value and
>   one or more color values to each such square

A primitive (e.g. a triangle) generates an area in the window. Let's say it can be enclosed inside a rectangle of pixels. Determining which of those pixels belong to the primitive depends on the implementation. Rectangles from different primitives may overlap, so a pixel may be "generated" by several primitives.

Once a pixel is "accepted" it may generate several fragments, likely due to antialiasing rules.

These fragments are sent to the fragment shader (once per primitive that generated them). Depending on their positions the "characteristics" (color, depth, or whatever 'out' value is set in the shader) are interpolated from the "characteristics" of the vertices of the primitive.

Each fragment shader (if not discards the fragment, and passes other tests like stencil, scissors, etc) combines its results for the pixel with the actual framebuffer, which has the result of the last combined result of the last proccessed fragment.

Comment: If don't mind, can you explain the specific algorithm? Ok, suppose I send three verices (triangle), then how to draw it? how to determine the color and any other things? Please explain detail.

Comment: If you are asking about what I wrote as "depends on the implementation" then 'derhass' and 'solidpixel' gave you some references. If your question is another one, please be more precise in what you wish to know.